# users#create works, but nothing is rendered

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I struggled already too much with this so I decided to ask.

Once the create action is executed I get a response from the `rails console` that the user is created however the render is not working. If I refresh the page the user is logged in and created but when executing the action, nothing happens. This is weather I do it through the html or js response of the #New action.

Meanwhile when I hit `submit`, I can see the response rendered in the `Chrome developer tools` => `network` => `preview`, but not within the browser itself. It just kinda gets stuck.
Please help. Any ideas why this might be happening?

This is my controller.

```
#User Sign-up 
def new
    @user = User.new
    @title =    "Inschrijven"
    @description = "Inschrijven als talent bij.."
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end
end

# Creates the basic user object from which can be created either a Jobseeker object or a Company object.
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  @title = "Inschrijven"
  @description = "Create a new user for 'region'."
  respond_to do |format|
    if user.save
        sign_in user
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path }
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the sign up form:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h2 class="alt1 center"><%= description %></h2>
<div class="row">

    <%= form_for(user, :url => { path: signup_path, via: 'post', action: 'create' }, :html => { remote: true, :class => "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
        <%= render "shared/error_messages" %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email, :class => "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control" %>
          </div>
        <span id="userEmailCheck"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password, "Wachtwoord", :class => "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.password_field :input_password, :class => "form-control" %>
        </div>
          <span><%= link_to((image_tag "tooltipicon.png"), "", :data => { toggle: "tooltip", placement: "right" }, :title => "Uw wachtwoord kan bestaan uit minimaal 6 en maximaal 20 tekens.") %></span>
      </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Herhaal wachtwoord", :class => "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => "form-control" %>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-4">
            <%= f.submit "Ga verder", class: "btn" %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You have a typo if action fails: ``format.html`enter code here` { render 'new' }`` (the *enter code here*)

Comment: Thanks for noticing man, but thats a typo in the post, not in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `remote: true` in your form definition. That means that the petition will be handled as javascript, using Rails built-in [unobtrusive javascript features](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for). You can check that the petition has a content-type *JS* instead of *HTML* in your server log.

Your controller should handle that case accordingly. Right now you are explicitly declaring the behavior for HTML petitions, and not defining any for JS ones. That is surely giving an exception on the server (and you will be able to see in the *network* tab on the Chrome dev tool).

Change your controller action to this one:

```
def create
  user = User.new(user_params)
  @title = "Inschrijven"
  @description = "Create a new user for 'region'."
  respond_to do |format|
    if user.save
        sign_in user
        format.html { redirect_to contact_path }
        format.js {}
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
      format.js {}
    end
  end
end
```

And then create a `create.js.erb` file on `app/views/users/` (assuming that your controller name is `UsersController`. That file should handle, in *Javascript*, what happens in the current view after the model is added.

---

Of course, an alternative will be to just remove the `remote: true` option from your form, if you just need HTML petitions with a redirect to `contact_path`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I just shouldn't have put the `remote:true`. Should work now.